# Why std::vector resize fails?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I am trying to resize vector defined over a defined custom class

```
class Product{
private:
    Product *next;
    int pid;

public:
    Product(int _pid): pid(_pid){}
};

int main(){
    vector<Product> v;
    v.resize(1, Product(1));
    v[0] = Product(1);
    cout<< v.size() << endl;
    v.resize(2, Product(2));
}
```

My code is failing when i try to resize it second time, I have looked over other answers but I couldn't really get the idea behind it.

I have a requirement where I need to resize the vector.

Could someone please explain it and any workaround for it?

Comment: `v[1]` is out-of-bounds access causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: Is use of `v[1]` due to misunderstanding or is it a typo?

Comment: It is not a typo and works fine the code is failing at `v.resize(2, Product(2))`. I have just tried it right now.

Comment: It fails at `v[1] = Product(1);`, it gives "Vector substrict out of range" error, because first index of `v` is `0`, not `1`.

Comment: `v[1] = Product(1);` is UB, might has destroyed something inside `std::vector`, and then crashed at `resize`.

Comment: I figured it out, resize just changes the size not the capacity of vector. I don't know the exact reason but it misbehaves when you assign  its second element something it misbehaves, however if you remove the last statement of the program it works fine. @songyuanyao you are right. But I still didn't get the idea why it is behaving like this. As I am new to c++, being a java programmer it is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to add new `Product` to your `vector` it would be a much easier to use `v.push_back(Product(1));` instead. This way you won't have to resize it by yourself.

But the answer to your question is that there is no problem with second resize, because after calling `v.resize(1, Product(1));`, the size of your `v` is `1`, and it can store only one object. (As a reminder first index of every `array`, `vector`, etc. is equal to `0`). Your program doesn't work because by using `v[1] = Product(1);` you try to access second index of your `vector`, and that's out of range.

If you change your `main` to this, the problem disappears:

```
int main(){
    vector<Product> v;
    v.resize(1, Product(1));
    v[0] = Product(1);
    v.resize(2, Product(2));
}
```

Comment: You are correct but vector has a capacity to accommodate elements within the capacity range. (I guess so because java behaves in that manner)

Comment: No Offences, but try removing the last line of the program and it works fine for me

Comment: It doesn't work for me when I leave `v[1]` and just delete the last line. It works when I change `v[1]` to `v[0]`. What error do you exactly get? Because while I tried to recreate your original code, it clearly stated that it ran out of range.

Comment: And I don't exactly know how this work in java, but even if it would, trying to access second element in array of size 1 is not what anyone should do. You can check capacity of vector by using `capacity()` method.

Comment: I got it, I am newbie to c++. Any comment on initial capacity of c++ vector.

Comment: When you first create vector object, it comes (or at least is should) with capacity of 0, you can change capacity without changing its size by calling `reserve()` instead of `resize()`.